# My re.sub statement gets hung up

Tags: python, regex

I'm a Python (and regex) rookie with relatively little programming experience outside of statistical packages (SAS & Stata).  So far, I've gotten by using Python tutorials and answers to other questions on stackoverflow, but I'm stuck.  I'm running Python 3.4 on Mac OS X.

I've written a script which downloads and parses SEC filings.  The script has four main steps:

1. Open the URL and load the contents to a string variable
2. remove HTML encoding using BeautifulSoup
3. remove other encoding with regex statements (like jpg definitions, embedded zip files, etc.)
4. save the resulting text file.

My goal is to remove as much of the "non-text" information as possible from each filing before saving to my local drive.  I have another script written where I do the actual analysis on the residual text.

I'm running into a problem with step 3 on at least one filing.  The line that is causing the hangup is:

```
_content1 = re.sub(r'(?i).*\.+(xls|xlsx|pdf|zip|jpg|gif|xml)+?[\d\D]+?(end)',r'',_content1)
```

where `_content` is a string variable containing contents of the SEC filing.  The regex statement is supposed to capture blocks beginning with a line ending in a file extension (xls, pdf, etc.) and ending on the word "end."

The above code has worked fine for entire years' worth of filings (i.e., I've analyzed all of 2001 and 2002 without issue), but my script is getting hung up on one particular filing in 2013 (http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/918160/0000918160-13-000024.txt).  I'm unsure how to debug as I'm not getting any error message.  The script just hangs up on that one line of code (I've verified this with print statements before and after).  Interestingly, if I replace the above line of code with this:

```
_content1 = re.sub(r'(?i)begin*.*(xls|xlsx|pdf|zip|jpg|gif|xml)+?[\d\D]+?(end)',r'',_content1)
```

Then everything works fine.  Unfortunately, certain kinds of embedded files in the filings don't start with "begin" (like zip files), so it won't work for me.

I'm hoping one of the resident experts can identify something in my regex substitution statement that would cause a problem, as going match-by-match through the linked SEC filing probably isn't feasible (at least I wouldn't know where to begin).  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
JRM

EDIT:

I was able to get my script working by using the following REGEX:

```
_content1 = re.sub(r'(?i)begin|\n+?.+?(xls|xlsx|pdf|zip|jpg|gif|xml)+?[\d\D]+?(end)',r'\n',_content1)
```

This seems to be accomplishing what I want, but I am still curious as to why the original didn't work if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is the lack of anchors.  Your original regex begins with `.*`, which can *start* matching anywhere and won't *stop* matching until it reaches a newline or the end of the text.  Then it starts backtracking, giving back one character at a time, trying to match the first falsifiable component of the pattern: the dot and the letters of the file extension.

So it starts at the beginning of the file and consumes potentially thousands of characters, only to backtrack all the way to the beginning before giving up.  Then it bumps ahead and does the same thing starting at the second character.  And again from the third character, from the fourth, and so on.  I know it seems incredibly dense, but that's the tradeoff we make for the power and compactness of regexes.

Try this regex:

```
r"(?im)^[^<>\n]+\.(?:xlsx?|pdf|zip|jpg|gif|xml)\n(?:(?!end$)\S+\n)+end\n"
```

The start anchor (`^`) in multiline mode makes sure the match can only start at the beginning of a line.  I used `[^<>\n]+` for the first part of the line because I'm working with the file you linked to; if you've removed all the HTML and XML markup, you might be able to use `.+` instead.

Then I used `(?:(?!end$).+\n)+` to match one or more complete lines that don't consist entirely of `end`.  It's probably more efficient than your `[\d\D]+?`, but the most important difference is that, when I do match `end`, I know it's at the beginning of the line (and the `$` ensures it's at the end of the line).

Comment: This does work, though I switched the `[^,.\n]` to `.+` like you suggest because I have stripped all the HTML tags.  It isn't perfect, though.  For some reason the jpg block in the linked file starting with "begin 644 a2012form10-k_chart.jpg" doesn't get replaced.  All the others do.  It seems like it should be capturing (and does when I test the regex on pythex.org).  But, at least the file will process, so I'm happy with the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following REGEX

```
_content1 = re.sub(r'(?i).*?\.+(xls|xlsx|pdf|zip|jpg|gif|xml)+?[\d\D]+?(end)',r'',_content1)
```

I've converted your * operation to *? which is non-greedy which is most likely what you want.

Comment: I think I do want non-greedy, but the script is still getting hung-up on that REGEX with your edits.  Thanks, though!